# Is there a way to update macOS offline?

Tags: macos, software-update

I am using a MacBook offline. Is it possible to Air Drop the latest version of the OS or something to this machine so that I can update it offline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**YES**

On another Mac go here

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/macos-monterey/id1576738294?mt=12

Or you could just search "macOS" on the app store if you prefer.

Click on the "GET" (or install...) link for "macOS Monterey" and let it download in full. You will know it is downloaded when the macOS installer runs and presents its opening screen, **don't do anything with the running installer!**

Go to your Applications folder and drag the "Install macOS Monterey" app onto a flash drive. Once that is done, quit the installer.

The installer will likely still be in Applications, you can keep it or trash it as you prefer.

Plug the flash drive into the Mac to be upgraded and launch the installer. You can copy it to the HD first or run the installer right off the flash drive, either should work fine.

Comment: Does the macOS installer tie itself to an AppleID like most applications do?

Comment: the macOS Installer does not associate with a particular Apple ID as it is free and can be installed (legally) on any Apple branded computer.

Answer (score 1):

For macOS versions up to 10.15, update packages are available directly from Apple: https://support.apple.com/downloads/macos

---

For macOS 11+, you'll only have access to "full" installers. (Some lists of direct links are available, e.g. https://mrmacintosh.com/macos-12-monterey-full-installer-database-download-directly-from-apple/.) After running those, an `Install macOS Monterey.app` application shows up in `/Applications`, which you can then use for updating.

From my testing though, this installer **still needs access to the internet**. Even if you run `/Applications/Install\ macOS\ Ventura.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia` to create a bootable USB drive.

[Apple documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372) says:

> A bootable installer doesn't download macOS from the internet, but it does require an internet connection to get firmware and other information specific to the Mac model.

---

Potential things to investigate, though these haven't worked for me:

- the Hackintosh install processes seem to get around this by manually repacking + reconstructing the install .dmg [[1](https://www.reddit.com/r/hackintosh/comments/jrrhox/how_to_make_a_full_offline_installer_for_macos_on/)], or
- manually unpacking SharedSupport.dmg [[2](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/macos-12-monterey-on-unsupported-macs-thread.2299557/page-62)].
- putting those modified .app installers onto a USB drive, to do a reboot + boot-from-USB install.
- following some of the [disable MDM notifications](https://gist.github.com/henrik242/65d26a7deca30bdb9828e183809690bd) steps, since you need to disable internet access at some point in the macOS install (seems to be after the final reboot/before the country select screen though, which means the system is still accessing the internet)

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't figure out why I downloaded a 12GB file and ran it and it finished in 3 seconds without updating my machine.  Looking in the Applications folder solved it!

Comment: you can sort of get around the need-for-internet by installing macOS to an external drive, then "restoring" the drive image to internal drive with Disk Utility, but that's really not an update.